getting error while fetching boards, "Client must be authenticated to access this resource."(Jira boards)
i am using the rest API to fetch projects and board using Oauth 2.0 authentication, after generate fresh access-token i am getting all projects list but when i am try to fetch boards i am getting error

Client must be authenticated to access this resource.

i thought might be having scope issue but i have already assigned read:board-scope:jira-software and read:project:jira but still getting the same error again and again.
